# jQuery animate div on mouse click

Tags: jquery, css

Situation, I have 3 block elements. In order:

-> Image

-> Hidden Text Block (.hidden)

-> footer block (.blockimage)

On load the image is overlaid over .hidden (basically further information), then a small block for the header. On mouse click .blockimage I want .hidden to slide above image.

Note: I have already set the .hidden element as position:absolute, it also has a inline style display:none. If I inspect .hidden and uncheck display:none. It appears perfect, however I can't seem to animate it on a on click call.

This is what I have done so far....

```
$('.blockimage').click(function() {
  $('.blockimage .hidden').slideUp('fast', function() {
    // remove display:none; of inline css on .hidden and slide content up. (Class already has a)
  });
});
```

Excluding the rotation, it would slide up similar to this = http://css-tricks.com/examples/SlideupBoxes/

Any help will be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a containing `div` hold both the image and the information, with `overflow: hidden`, then animate position on click. Here is a **[demo](http://jsbin.com/odiyeb/1)**.

### Html

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="{yourimage}" />
    <div class="info-block">
     {information}
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

Here is just the necessary CSS to make it work.

```
.container {

  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.info-block {

  position: absolute;
  bottom: -xx; // element height, or more

}
```

### Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $('img').click(function(){

    $(this).siblings('.info-block').animate({
      bottom: '0'}, 'fast');

  });

});
```

### Update: return to initial state (just jQuery or CSS3 Transition)

If you want it to return to initial state, you could extend on the code I gave you by making your javascript check the `bottom` property, like so:

```
if( $(this).siblings('.info-block').css('bottom') !== '0px' )
    $(this).siblings('.info-block').animate({bottom: 0}, 'fast');
else
    $(this).siblings('.info-block').animate({bottom: '-{some-other-height}'}, 'fast');
```

You can check a working [**demo**](http://jsbin.com/odiyeb/4).

However, in this case I would perhaps use **CSS3 transition**, just to have a cleaner and lighter code. Of course you could use transition even in the case you didn't want it to go back, but in that case I found a quick jQuery faster.

#### Solution 2: CSS3 Transitions

If you want to use CSS3 Transition, define another class like so:

```
.info-block.shown {

    bottom: 0;

}
```

Then toggle the class using jQuery on click:

```
$('img').click(function(){

      $(this).siblings('.info-block').toggleClass('shown');

});
```

Working [**demo here**](http://jsbin.com/odiyeb/5).

Comment: Sorted :)

Just out of interest, how by return do I get the .hidden element to return to the prior hidden state?

E.G -> Secondary Click = return to initial state?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('.hidden').slideUp`, your current selector is trying to match all elements with both classes.

Additionally, `slideUp` [hides](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) the selected elements, try using `show` instead.

Comment: Hm? Not really. A selector for both classes would look like `.blockimage.hidden`, while the selector `.blockimage .hidden` selects the elements with a class of `hidden` which are descendant of elements with a class of `blockimage`.